# Define JSON variable from array

Tags: arrays, json

Can someone tell me how to define a JSON variable from an array?

API endpoint wants to receive a number from the POST request and that number is contained in an array:

```
"template_job_id": "4109170002"
```

x is stored in this array and should be `value = 4109170002`

```
"custom_fields_values": [
{
"id": 122709143,
"custom_field_id": 1202201,
"name": "ID",
"value": "4109170002",
"attachment": null,
"options": "",
"type": 1,
"type_name": "Text",
"entity": null,
"user": null,
"show_on_portal": false,
"mandatory": true
},
{
"id": 121273903,
"custom_field_id": 1202206,
"name": "Verified Title",
"value": "",
"attachment": null,
"options": "",
"type": 1,
"type_name": "Text",
"entity": null,
"user": null,
"show_on_portal": null,
"mandatory": true
}
],
```

Comment: do u mean like var a = {"custom_fields_values": [
{
"id": 122709143,
"custom_field_id": 1202201,
"name": "ID",
"value": "4109170002",
"attachment": null,
"options": "",
"type": 1,
"type_name": "Text",
"entity": null,
"user": null,
"show_on_portal": false,
"mandatory": true
},
{
"id": 121273903,
"custom_field_id": 1202206,
"name": "Verified Title",
"value": "",
"attachment": null,
"options": "",
"type": 1,
"type_name": "Text",
"entity": null,
"user": null,
"show_on_portal": null,
"mandatory": true
}
]}
then to access value we write a.custom_fields_values[0].value

Comment: I am not sure if I understood the question correctly.